# Check out Git with Chef and Vagrant

Tags: git, virtualization, provisioning, chef-infra, vagrant

I want to use Vagrant as my production machine for a few projects I'm working on. It would be ideal if I could configure Vagrant using Chef Solo to checkout the latest version of my code. This would drastically improve testing.

Currently I have a recipe using the following:

```
git "Checkout Code" do
    repository "git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/git.git"
    reference "master" # or "HEAD" or "TAG_for_1.0" or (subversion) "1234"
    action :checkout
    destination "/home/vagrant/git"
end
```

Just as a proof of concept, I'm using a public repository.

I get the following as an error:

```
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.10 ***
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[test_app::deploy]"] from JSON
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Run List is [recipe[test_app::deploy]]
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Run List expands to [test_app::deploy]
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Starting Chef Run for lucid32
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Running start handlers
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: Processing git[Checkout Code] action checkout (test_app::deploy line 23)
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] INFO: git[Checkout Code] cloning repo git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/git.git to /home/vagrant/git
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] ERROR: git[Checkout Code] (test_app::deploy line 23) has had an error
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] ERROR: git[Checkout Code] (/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/test_app/recipes/deploy.rb:23:in `from_file') had an error:
git[Checkout Code] (test_app::deploy line 23) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - git clone  git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/git.git /home/vagrant/git
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:213:in `exec'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:213:in `fork_subprocess'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:203:in `fork'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:203:in `fork_subprocess'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:35:in `run_command'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mixlib-shellout-1.0.0.rc.1/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:216:in `run_command'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:30:in `shell_out'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:35:in `shell_out!'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/provider/git.rb:125:in `clone'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/provider/git.rb:43:in `action_checkout'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:454:in `send'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:454:in `run_action'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:85:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:85:in `each'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:85:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:330:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:163:in `run'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:207:in `run_application'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:195:in `loop'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:195:in `run_application'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:70:in `run'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.10/bin/chef-solo:25
/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo:19
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[Sun, 17 Jun 2012 04:08:49 +0200] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: git[Checkout Code] (test_app::deploy line 23) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - git clone  git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/git.git /home/vagrant/git
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm a fool. I didn't add the "git" recipe to my Vagrantfile first. Result? Trying to use git before it's installed on the system.